# Why is the redirection operator being interpreted as a file in R's system() call?

Tags: r

Simple commands like:
`system(command = "cat file1 > file2")`

Yield the error:
`/usr/bin/cat: >: No such file or directory`

Which means that `>` is being interpreted as a file. Why does this happen and how can I get around it? I'm running this on Windows 10 Rstudio R 4.0. Worth nothing that the commands themselves work fine as in `system("cat file1")` prints the expected contents to stdout.

Comment: How do you have a "/usr/bin/cat" on a Windows 10 machine? Are you running a linux subsystem or something?

Comment: I have cygwin installed, but other than that I didn't do anything fancy

Comment: How about `system2("cat", c("file1"), stdout = "file2")`? (I added parens around the second argument because it really represents "all but the command itself", as a vector. It still blindly concatenates all arguments without quoting ...)

Comment: thats it, maybe you can post a short answer pointing this out, surely it will be useful for disracted users like me (:

Comment: Which is it ... @MrFlick's comment or mine?

Comment: @MrFlick comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running

```
cat file1 > file2
```

You are relying on the shell to do the redirection for you. When you run `system()` on a linux machine, it will create a shell for you, but when you use `system()` on Windows, it doesn't run a full shell, it just tries to execute the command. Thus, you need to use `shell()` instead.

```
shell(command = "cat file1 > file2")
```

This is discussed further in the Note section of the `?system` help page.

Answer (score 2):

(This answer provided mostly as an informing alternative to MrFlick's recommendation to use `shell`.)

`system2` is *slightly less-bad* than `system`. One way it is marginally better is that it allows one to do redirection in the arguments, with `stdout=` and `stderr=` arguments. That makes your command:

```r
system2("cat", "file1", stdout = "file2")
```

Be careful, though, R's `system` command is horribly risky for all but the simplest command sequences (or the most paranoid). For comparison,

- `system()` takes a single string, making the caller handle any quoting;
- `system2()` allows you to provide a vector of arguments, which to me *suggests* that it will deal with quoting and such ... but from its source:

  ```r
  command <- paste(c(shQuote(command), env, args), collapse = " ")
  ```

  which only protects the command itself, leaving the rest of the args blindly space-collapsed.

An alternative is to use the `processx` package to run commands, as it deals with all of that for you ... as well as several other safeguards and bells and whistles.

Comment: I agree this is probably a better way to tackle the problem. Mine was just more to explain what was going on.

Comment: "better" is always relative, especially when yours "just works" :-)